# A set of students have just a name at first. From their 1st exam on they will have both name and score. How to design this is a simple way?

Tags: c#, java, oop, design-patterns

I have a set of `Individual`s at first:

```
class Individual {
    double characteristics[];
    abstract double CalculateValue();
    ...
}
```

Each individual has a set of characteristics. Those characteristics will be implemented by the user of my library through inheritance:

```
class MyIndividualABC : Individual {
    public MyIndividualABC() {
        characteristics = new double[2];
        characteristics[0] = 123;
        characteristics[1] = 456;
    }

    public override double CalculateValue() { 
        return characteristics[0] / characteristics[1]; //for example
    }
}
```

I will then take them and give to each one of them a score (based on their value). I will call this doing an iteration.

```
class EvaluatedIndividual {
    double value;
    double score; //score was calculated based on value
}
```

From iteration2 and beyond, I will be always having at hand objects of type `EvaluatedIndividual`. But the first time, I will have to lead with objects of type `Individual`.

I wouldn't like to have to treat the first iteration in a different way than the other ones. How should I approach this?

*An analogy would be to have a class of students. Before the first exam, you just know their names, and from the 1st exam on you will have both their names and the average of the scores of their exams up to that moment.*

I have devised 3 different ways to handle this:

1. I will have a `Start()` method on my program and then an `Iteration()`. The `Start()` takes `Individual[]` while the `Iteration()` takes `EvaluatedIndividual[]`. Hacky, but will work wonders. Will use this if nothing better comes up.
2. `EvaluatedIndividual` inherits from `Individual`. This looks clean, but I am not too sure about it because I'd like `Individual` to be an interface and my idea would be to allow the client of my library/framework to inherit from it and define a set of methods/fields on `Individual` as he wants (`Individual` could have multiple values that'd be taken into consideration for calculating `value`, for instance) . If I follow this approach, I'd have to make him also implement a class from `EvaluatedIndividual`.
3. Individual is formed by value and a both `evaluation` and `wasEvaluated`. At first wasEvaluated was false, so any attempt to gather `value` throws up an Exception. I don't particulary like this, but I am not sure why.

How'd you approach this? This is probably a pretty common pattern, but I am afraid I don't know any GoF pattern that matches this scenario :(

Thanks

Comment: You mean, an instance of `Individual` becomes an `EvaluatedIndividual` after an exam? The world is really changing fast...

Answer (score 3):

I'm all for simple; I'd just have one class here. In C# maybe use `Nullable<T>`:

```
double? Score {get;set;}
```

In Java  (which obviously lacks `Nullable<T>`), maybe just expose the score along with an `isEvaluated` flag (or a count of the number of exams evaluated) - if this is `false` (or `0`) you just ignore the score.

Comment: I probably oversimplified the situation in the OP. I have a Individual that will be evaluated taking in consideration features that will be defined through implementation of the Individual interface. With that characteristics I'll build the "value" that'll be used to score the Individual.

Comment: @devouredelysium - so... add an interface that each implementation can implement? However, I still maintain that only one interface is necessary...

Answer (score 2):

I would have one class with a special value for `score` that denotes that the individual hasn't been evaluated:

```
class Individual {
    private double value;
    private double score = -1; // score was calculated based on value,
                               // -1 means not evaluated

    public boolean isEvaluated() { return score != -1; }
}
```

IMHO inheritance is an overkill here.

Comment: A naughty boy got 0 in the exam, and he drew a rabbit on his paper, so the teacher took extra 1 score out. Finally he got -1 in the exam. Maybe changing -1 to `double.minvalue` is better?

Comment: @vitaut: Cent percent agreement. Inheritance is not an overkill here, but completely out of question. It doesn't suit here.

Comment: @Danny: That teacher deserves a termination letter whatsoever, especially when its Drawing/Art exam.

Comment: Using this will lead to if code. I have always to check whether the individual was evaluated or not, which is something I don't find that interesting.

Comment: @Adeel: What I want to say is that sometimes we may get -1 score in an exam, it's possible.

Comment: @devoured: Its better to use `if()..` than incorporating some kind of hack which make the whole code bloated. BTW, its not always about something interesting when writing code. The code should be simple and must make sense, no matter if that's boring.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, if this isn't some kind of classroom exercise, don't make things over complicated. GoF patterns aren't for everything you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Individual {
  double score;
  ScoreState scoreState;
}
```

I've found whenever I need one state, I need 2, and then I shortly need 2+n, so may as well make an enum, this allows for situations like "Pending Review" and other such considerations, which may be handy in the future, and it prevents against an excess of flags, which can be confusing.

Comment: That is not really the point of what I am looking for. Each Individual has a set of characteristics that'll be evaluated. The client of my framework will want to define what those characteristics are and how to take them into consideration. Maybe it wasn't obvious from the OP. Having enums will just lead to if code.